# Converting Pixels from int to unsigned byte in JAVA

Tags: java, int, byte, pixel, unsigned

Im trying to convert the pixels that i get from the getRGB function of a black and white image to unsigned byte, I have read and, correct if I am wrong, the getRGB function in java returns integer values, so what I want to do is to see values from 0-255 not the negative integer values Im getting with the function. I have tried this with no sucess:

```
   int width;
   int height;
   byte extract;
   int asign;
   int matrix[][];

 for ( i = 0; i < height; i++)
     {
        for ( j = 0; j < width; j++) 
        {
            extract =(byte)(xray.getRGB(j, i));
            asign = (int)extract;
            //asign = asign & 0xff;
            asign = asign + 128;
            matrix[i][j] = asign;


        }
     }
```

Notice that xray is a buferred image.
Hope you can help me with this issue guys. As you can see I've tried with mask, also I 've tried trying to add 128 to the value after the cast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, `getRGB()` returns a signed `int`, but it's a 32-bit `int` representing the alpha and R, G, B values. The most significant byte is alpha, and if it's fully opaque then that will be 255, which means you'll end up with a negative `int` overall.

If you want to mask out the alpha value, you can do it with

```
matrix[i][j] = xray.getRGB(j,i) & 0xFFFFFF;
```

which will get rid of the high-order byte. This will leave you with a single positive value containing the RGB values for the pixel.

Careful what you do with it afterwards: if you then try to use it to set the colour of a pixel later, you might end up setting the alpha value to 0 (now that you've masked it off), and so you'll end up with something fully transparent (aka invisible).

If it's a black and white image and for some reason you're getting just values from -128 to 127, then more or less the same trick applies to make it unsigned. In fact exactly the same line as above would do it, but you could also shorten the mask:

```
matrix[i][j] = xray.getRGB(j,i) & 0xFF;
```

This means you don't need any `if`-`else` in your code to get it working, and you don't need your `extract` or `asign` variables.

Comment: Thanks, I have another question, if the image that Im working with it, it's a black and white image, it's supossed to contain a matrix and all the values in this matrix have to be betwween 0 to 255, correct? My question here, it's if internally the computer still seeing the 4 channels (alfa, red, green, blue) or just see one channel, in other words, the pixels are composed by 4 values, or just one???

Comment: @LaloGalicia It might be *stored* either way. Eventually it will need to be converted to pixel data for the whole screen, though, which will be RGB. These days, lots of the heavy lifting gets done by the graphics card and the CPU never has to worry about it. So it depends on what you mean by *internally*: there are lots of different layers!

Comment: thanks @chiastic-security , I will try what you told me, and let you know my results :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    extract =(byte)(xray.getRGB(j, i));
    if(extract < 0){
       asign = extract + 256;  // Add the total number of values in byte if extract is negative
    }
    else{
       asign = extract;        // You don't need to type cast it to int explicitly
    }
    matrix[i][j] = asign;
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try.  I have another question, if the image that Im working with it, it's a black and white image, it's supossed to contain a matrix and all the values in this matrix have to be betwween 0 to 255, correct? My question here, it's if internally the computer still seeing the 4 channels (alfa, red, green, blue) or just see one channel, in other words, the pixels are composed by 4 values, or just one???